# Concatenate two arrays into a new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have two arrays,

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = np.array([100,101])
```

I want to concatenate them so that `b` is added a column on the right-hand side so we have a new array `A | b` that would be something like:

1  2  3  100

4 5 6 101

I am trying with concatenate this way:

```
new = np.concatenate((A, b), axis=1)
```

But I get the next error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s), and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

How can I concatenate these two arrays?

Comment: Do you understand the `shape` of your arrays, and their respective number of dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
>>> np.column_stack((A, b))

array([[  1,   2,   3, 100],
       [  4,   5,   6, 101]])
```

which takes care of `b` not being 2D.

---

To make `concatenate` work, we manually make `b` of shape `(2, 1)`:

```
>>> np.concatenate((A, b[:, np.newaxis]), axis=1)

array([[  1,   2,   3, 100],
       [  4,   5,   6, 101]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also Transpose A do a vertical stack and then transpose it back `np.vstack((A.T,b)).T`